# Javascript - How to convert this to return a Promise?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I have this code I'm copying from a SaaS's example code, how to get the right URL for some action.  The example code looks like this, but I want it to return a Promise so I can use `await` with it in the code flow.  It's tripping me up how to structure it properly though, probably some head-against-the-wall reason.

```
getSourceUrl: async(customerInfo) => {
   Saas.getSaasClient()
      .post(`${customerInfo.customerUrl}/funding-sources`, customerInfo.requestBody)
      .then(res => res.headers.get('location'));
}
```

In the code flow...

```
const sourceUrl = await getSourceUrl(customerInfo);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're just not returning it:

```js
getSourceUrl: async(customerInfo) => {
   return Saas.getSaasClient()
      .post(`${customerInfo.customerUrl}/funding-sources`, customerInfo.requestBody)
      .then(res => res.headers.get('location'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something easy I was just overlooking